# including files from /var/www in apache virtualhost subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost

I've been having this problem for a while and still can't come up with a proper solution - I want to include files from directories within `/var/www` from my Apache server. This isn't a problem whenever I'm including anything from any of the directories within `/var/www` but my subdomain (also coming from a directory in `/var/www`) isn't behaving well.

Here's the virtualhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName support.cruisetouch.com
ServerAlias cruisetouch.com/Support
ServerRoot /var/www/

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Support

<Directory /var/www/html/Support>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I usually include files with PHP like so:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/_INCLUDES/Header.php"; ?>
```

and they would be pulled from the `/var/www/_INCLUDES` directory, but whenever I use this line of code in `/var/www/Support` (the subdomain directory) it thinks that I'm looking within THAT directory.

How can I include files from `/var/www` without it treating `/var/www/Support` as the document root? Linking directly to the files isn't an option either.

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Running Apache on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that it would behave better if you used `SERVER_ROOT` instead of `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in your PHP include.

Edit for right answer from comments : My bad, this var doesn't seem to be available in the $_SERVER array. Try to simply change the include to $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."../../_INCLUDES/Header.php"; ?>

Comment: Gives back the error of _Warning: include(/_INCLUDES/Header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/Support_ is again thinking that the root is /Support, but the ServerRoot in the VHost file was explicitly put as /var/www

Comment: My bad, this var doesn't seem to be available in the $_SERVER array. Have you tried to simply change the include to $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."../../_INCLUDES/Header.php"; ?>

Comment: Bam. Legend. That works if you browse through the subdomain, but not if you go to cruisetouch.com/Support - I'll probably just add a redirect :)